# How to drop child element when parent is dragged

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I have an element (the parent), I can drag and drop, inside it has a child element, which can not be dragged apart, but that is dragged along with the parent.

Also, there is some area that you can fold the child element.

When I drag the parent I need to get the area that you can drag respond to child.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".parent").draggable({});
     $(".drop-area").droppable({
         tolerance: touch
         , over: function(){
            $(".drop-area").css("background-color","#C00");
         }
         , deactivate:function(){
            $(".drop-area").css("background-color","#000");
         }              
     });
}
```

CSS:

```
.parent { position: relative; width: 200px; height: 200px; background: green; }
.child  { position: relative; width: 100px; height: 50px; background: red; right: 0; bottom: -50px;  }
.drop-area { position: absolute; width: 150px; height: 150px; bottom: 0; right: 0; background: bloack; }
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class"parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="drop-area"></div>
</body>
```